# Angular scope value can't access from another function in the same controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

In my Angular controller there are two functions.Normally it should able to access $scope value from other function since it's in the same controller.But i can't access it.I have added two console.log() in both function.First function retrieves the scope value because i can see it prints the value in console.But in the second function, it showing an undefined variable.Hope someone will help me to solve the this issue.

Following is my code,

First function

```
   //Get user id
    $scope.getUserId = function() {
        UserService.getCurrentUser().then(function(response) {
            if (response.query_status == "success") {
                $scope.userid = response.data.id;
                console.log('User id is: '+ $scope.userid);
            }
            else {
                $scope.userid = null;
            }
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.userid = null;
            console.log("Error : Failed to load user data...");
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Second function

```
   //Access user id
    $scope.accessUserId = function() {
        console.log('User id from other function is:'+ $scope.userid);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Can you add the snippet of code?

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Please create a plunker

Comment: Hello, please outside of your first function 'getUserId', on the top, initialize  the userId variable to null like this : $scope.userid = null;//init

Comment: I did that way as well.But now i'm getting varibale null valaue.

Comment: I created a plunker.Link-https://plnkr.co/edit/CJp29Y8QOgLMt2mFrDWr

Comment: Is there any difference of angular versions when defining $scope?I'm using Angular version 1.4.

Comment: And i'm getting the response from a Angular service which has a $promise :)

Comment: Hope someone will help me to solve this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to solve this.I needed to use Angular $q.defer() method.There was some delay for processing the response for the other function.